# Как узнать количество пикселей от верха страницы до текущего экрана?

Tags: jquery

Есть страница высота которой больше высоты экрана. Другими словами появляется скролбар.

Как узнать расстояние (количество пикселей?) от верха СТРАНИЦЫ до верха ЭКРАНА, когда страница прокручивается вниз?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы имеете ввиду:

```
var cont_top = window.pageYOffset ? window.pageYOffset : document.body.scrollTop;
```

?

Comment: Если честно, я не совсем уверен, что именно я имею ввиду. Но попробую так)